# Search Result Web part affect on Content Search Web part ,both webpart on same page

Tags: development, search-results, enterprise-search, testing

Currently on single page having both Search Result Web part and Content Search Web part,
if enter any keyword in Search Result Web part it display result but at the same time Content Search Web also get affected which is on same page ....

Content Search Web Should Not Change... 
help me to  resolve this issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes due to query string variables. if your page is having URL with query string #k=YOURKEYWORD then it will reflect in any content search web part. Find a way that would pass query string in this format
 #Default={"k":"test"} 
where test is your actual keyword.

I took a hint from this article http://techmikael.blogspot.in/2013/09/appending-query-terms-in-sharepoint.html